# Why does this webpage use Javascript to display the date of the article?

Tags: javascript, datetime, date

I came across this [webpage](http://www.pcworld.com/businesscenter/article/181590/verizon_droid_tethering_will_cost_you.html) in which the date of the article is an integer which is formatted by an inline call to a JavaScript function into the string "Nov 6, 2009 10:17am".

The markup looks like this

```
<small>
  <script type="text/javascript">timestamp(1257520620000,'longDateTime')</script>
</small>
```

Is there a good reason to deal with dates in this way? I'm having a hard time thinking of one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best idea I can come up with is they would display in the correct time zone and local format for the visitor.

Comment: Agreed, can't think of another reason. As for the OPs question of it being a good way of dealing with dates I'd argue against it, seems like a lot of work to avoid using a simple timezone after the time and doing it all server side rather than blocking rendering to do it without client side.

Answer (score 1):

This may be to deal with times zones and the effect of changes to time for day light saving, so the time is stored as some UTC or Unix time, e.g. a number of seconds/milliseconds since and known starting point. Then rendered for each user based on their location.

This is fairly common on international applications.

Answer (score 0):

I think they want to hide the date from news crawlers